# What database model to use?

Tags: database-design, application-design

I am about to start a SaaS application for companies (clients of the app) to mange their employees, customers. Application would have different roles in it such as admin, manager etc.

Do you use separate db for each client or single db for every client in such project? What database would be suitable for that?

Comment: Without some metrics / parameters/ limits, it is opinion based

Comment: Here are some thoughts/pros and cons https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/how-design-multiclient-databases/

Answer (score 1):

Do this: [go to the Sales department and ask](https://www.jeeja.biz/2022/03/13/azure-should-i-use-single-tenant-or-multi-tenant/) :

- Have we spoke with each one of our customers?
- Do we have their phone numbers in our CRM?
- Do we have their office location?

If the reply is **YES** you have **Customers**, therefore you have to go **single tenant** and dedicate one database per customer.

If you cannot name your customers because your application has a number of users that come and go… and they can create their own account with an e-mail and they are in... you don't have customers, you have **users**, therefore use **multi tenant**.